# Query Posts by Custom Field 'Price'

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, wp-query

I'd like to display all posts within a given price range. For example: When a user inputs 100 and 1000 (in two separate form fields) - my site will display all posts that have a custom field called price that has a numeric value between 100 and 1000.

Found this under the documentation for WP Query; however, I'm unsure as to how I create a query based on input from a form on my WordPress site.

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'color',
        'value' => 'blue',
        'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'price',
        'value' => array( 20, 100 ),
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    )
)
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: have a look at the examples for [`WP_Query` Custom Field Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

Comment: Maybe I need to clarify my question. I'm stuck as to how I connect this query with a form on the front end of my website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action to detect some filter vars in the URL and filter the query accordingly.

For example, say your form sets `price_low` and `price_high` GET vars, so the URL looks like:

```
domain.com/?price_low=100&price_high=1000
```

Then your filter function checks for the presence of those vars and creates the `meta_query`. This example is checking if it's the main query on the home page, see the [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) page for how to check if other types of queries are happening, like a category or tag, etc..

```
function wpa_filter_home_query( $query ){
    if( $query->is_home()
    && $query->is_main_query()
    && isset( $_GET['price_low'] )
    && isset( $_GET['price_high'] ) ) {
        $meta_query = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'price',
                'value' => array( $_GET['price_low'], $_GET['price_high'] ),
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
            )
        );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa_filter_home_query' );
```

EDIT- example of a simple form to submit values. Omitting the `action` attribute will submit the form to the current page.

```
<form method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="price_low">
    <input type="text" name="price_high">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Milo! The problem I'm having is with setting 'price_low' and 'price_high' GET vars through a form. Can you provide an example of this?

Comment: see edit above.

Comment: EDIT: just going to ask another question (don't want to get off topic).

Comment: Totally got this working. Wish I could up-vote you again Milo! Thanks a million.

Comment: Trying to combine this query with the Multiple Category Selection widget - any ideas as to how I can make it all happen in one query? Right now the user has to submit 2 queries. I've posted another question here: (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91701/query-problem-show-posts-within-category-x-that-have-a-custom-field-between) thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I had luck with the [Custom Query Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-query-fields/) plugin for this exact issue before.

I'm not 100% sure it will work as it hasn't been updated for a year but it may be worth a go.

Comment: I've used that plugin, and it provides me with the URL that I need. For example, if I use:
`register_custom_queryable_field("price", array("dataType"=>"numeric"));`
and then a link like this: `http://www.yoursite.com/?price_min=200&price_max=800&order_by=price` it will do what I want. The problem I'm having is connecting a web form with this process (I don't want a user to type in a url, or click a link for a pre-determined range. They should be able to set their own numeric values with a form. Make sense?

Answer (score -1):

Thank you Milo
some edit in your code

```
function wpa_filter_home_query( $query ){
    if( $query->is_home()
    && $query->is_main_query()
    && isset( $_GET['price_low'] )
    && isset( $_GET['price_high'] ) ) {
        $meta_query = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'price',
                'value' => $_GET['price_low'],
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => '>='
            )
        );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
        $meta_query = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'price',
                'value' => $_GET['price_high'],
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => '<='
            )
        );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa_filter_home_query' );
```

Comment: This is the same anser Milo gave but instead of a `BETWEEN` statement you use two compare statements.